# Using putExtra to pass an image

Tags: java, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

My app is getting data from Firebase database, then I'm using it for a CardView, once its clicked, it opens a new activity and uses the image for the new activity.

I'm using putExtra to move the card data to the new activity.
But, I have a small problem moving an Image using the putExtra..
I've looked up on the Internet and found out that I can do that by using Bitmap as the following -

```
Bitmap tileImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imageName);
```

The issue here is that my Image is stored on Firebase, I use the Image on the Recyclerview's Cardview.. how can I use that Image from that location?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It is not advisable to pass an image through intent extras. You can get the image link and pass it through the Intent extras. Later, you can use Picasso to load the image from the URL. Picasso gives you better caching mechanism as Bitmap's are costly in terms of perfomance.

Comment: I'm sorry but you said it's not advisable to pass an image though Intent extras but later you said that I should pass it though the Intent extras? I'm a bit confused.. and how can I get the link of the image if its on firebase and it's changing if the image is changed.

Comment: What I'm saying is that get a URL link to the image and pass it as a string through Intent extras. Do not pass the whole bitmap as an Intent extra. I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: In the case of Firebase Storage, you just need to pass the URI for the image reference for the specific bucket. You can then use the normal Firebase way to load the image as soon as you have the URI reference.